# Angular $http.get have empty response data if server response 500 Internal server error

Tags: angularjs

Please refer jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vom4za2z/7/

I use $http.get to catch response data when server response error 500 Internal Server Error.

But in error callback function, it alway return response object with data=null and status=-1

Check in "Network" tab of Developer tools of Google Chrome browser, you will see response from server with status code is 500 and response data like:

```
{
"AppCode": null,
"HttpCode": 500,
"Url": "\/api\/categories\/getList.json",
"Message": "Expired token",
"Details": null
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I get response data?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Have you double check Bearer token is valid?

Comment: The token is expired and I want to catch error response data in this case